# How can i randomize question in a quiz app

Tags: android

I made a simple quiz on Android Studio which contains 3+ questions. How to make the questions become random without duplicated. This app does not use a database. I'm new to programming so I don't know what to do about this

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.AlertDialog; import android.graphics.Color; import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

TextView totalQuestionsTextView;
TextView questionTextView;
Button ansA,ansB,ansC,ansD;
Button submitBtn;

int score=0;
int totalQuestions = QuestionAnswer.question.length;
int currentQuestionIndex = 0;
String selectedAnswer = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    totalQuestionsTextView = findViewById(R.id.total_questions);
    questionTextView = findViewById(R.id.question);
    ansA = findViewById(R.id.ans_A);
    ansB = findViewById(R.id.ans_B);
    ansC = findViewById(R.id.ans_C);
    ansD = findViewById(R.id.ans_D);
    submitBtn = findViewById(R.id.submbit_btn);

    ansA.setOnClickListener(this);
    ansB.setOnClickListener(this);
    ansC.setOnClickListener(this);
    ansD.setOnClickListener(this);
    submitBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    totalQuestionsTextView.setText("Total Questions : "+totalQuestions);

    loadNewQuestion();


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    ansA.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ansB.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ansC.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    ansD.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Button clickedButton = (Button) view;
    if(clickedButton.getId()==R.id.submbit_btn){
        currentQuestionIndex++;
        loadNewQuestion();



    }else{
        //choices button clicked
        selectedAnswer = clickedButton.getText().toString();
        clickedButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
    }

}

void loadNewQuestion(){

    if(currentQuestionIndex == totalQuestions){
        finishQuiz();
        return;
    }

    questionTextView.setText(QuestionAnswer.question[currentQuestionIndex]);
    ansA.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][0]);
    ansB.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][1]);
    ansC.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][2]);
    ansD.setText(QuestionAnswer.choices[currentQuestionIndex][3]);


}
void finishQuiz(){

    String passStatus = "";
    if (score > totalQuestions*0.60){
        passStatus = "Passes";
    }else{
        passStatus = "Failed";
    }

     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
             .setTitle(passStatus)
             .setMessage("Score is "+score+" out of "+ totalQuestions)
             .setPositiveButton("Restart",(dialogInterface, i) -> restartQuiz())
             .setCancelable(false)
             .show();

}

void restartQuiz(){
    score = 0;
    currentQuestionIndex = 0;
    loadNewQuestion();
}
```

QuestionAnswer.java

```
import java.util.Arrays; import java.util.List; import java.util.Random;

public class QuestionAnswer {

public static String[] question = {
        "Which company own the android?",
        "Which one is not the programming language?",
        "Where are you watching this video"

};

public static String choices[][] = {
        {"Google", "Apple", "Nokia", "Samsung"},
        {"Java", "Kotlin", "Notepad", "Python"},
        {"Facebook", "Whatsapp", "Instagram", "Youtube"},
};

public static String correctAnswers[] = {
        "Google",
        "Notepad",
        "Youtube"

};
```

}

how can i add shuffle.collection or random to make my app show random question instead

Comment: First create a custom class for question and answer, after that you can use the shuffle function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out about `Random` class first in Java. Thereafter, you will create a random number using Random class in `onClick` function, then set a question's index to your Random number

Comment: Could you add some example code for OP?

Comment: I can't give you a code example, but I will share with you a useful link → https://www.javatpoint.com/post/java-random

Comment: If you can't provide an example, then there was no point in answering the question in this case, as OP clearly doesn't know about the Random class. Sure, he could do some more research on his own, but he asked the question here for a reason